# "INIT: version 2.86 reloading" - cause and fix?

Tags: linux, init

> INIT: version 2.86 reloading

appears on screen.

Encountered this error and it seems there is no other way to fix this other than rebooting the system.

- unable to ssh in,
- unable to login via console.

Any other way to fix this issue without rebooting it?

Comment: @regemaster init periodically reloads afaik. are you able to otherwise login? have you been able to retrieve the log history to see what was going on before the reboot was required?

Answer (score 11):

This is not an error. You can ignore it.

This is an information note that indicates that `init` has reloaded `/etc/inittab`. Probably the result of a package upgrade that touched something in there.

You'll have to look elsewhere for the cause of your problems.